How do you enable runtime-repack in llama cpp python?
After updating llama-cpp-python I am getting an error when trying to run an ARM optimized GGUF model TYPE_Q4_0_4_4 REMOVED, use Q4_0 with runtime repacking. After looking into it, the error comes from this change to llama.cpp. From what I can tell, if you set the GGML_CPU_AARCH64 cmake flag to ON then this feature should be enabled. I tried doing this with a force reinstall CMAKE_ARGS="-DGGML_CPU_AARCH64=ON" pip install llama-cpp-python --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir, but it did not work, and in the output I don't think this flag was enabled.
When I try using a Q4_0 model the performance is far worse than the Q4_0_4_4 was, how do I enable runtime repacking in llama.cpp when using llama-cpp-python so I can leverage ARM specific model optimizations?

this may be a bug in llama.cpp
